# Specifiy a combined target in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU Make, how can I ensure other targets dependencies are made before a final task runs?

(I know this is a a bit of an abuse of make, but can it be done?)

Say I have 2 targets a and b. Building just a or just b is easy, but I want to trigger a special type of build if targetting both a and b.

For example, my Makefile (simplified from a real problem)

```
a_prereq:
    @echo "making a"

b_prereq:
    @echo "making b"

a: a_prereq default
b: b_prereq default

default:
    @echo "made!"
```

Calling `make a` prints `making a; made!`. This is correct.

Calling `make b` prints `making b; made!`. This is correct.

Calling `make a b` prints `making a; made!; making b`. Not what I wanted!

How do I get `make a b` to print `making a; making b; made!;` if I can only change the makefile and not the calling `make a b`.

(I know I could I could introduce `c: a_prereq b_prereq default` and call `make c` but can it be done without the new target?)

Comment: I think there's a way, but it's a monstrous hack. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: So, you want `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` to always be made before `default`? Why don't you simply declare `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` as prerequisites of `default` (`default: a_prereq b_prereq`)? Note: printing `making a` while indeed making `a_prereq` does not really help understanding your problem.

Comment: @Beta I suspected it might need something nasty! This is really representative of a real problem where a and b represent different "flavours" of a build, with the option that having both is desirable in certain circumstances.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet not always, default is valid on its own, but I want to be able to customise the default build with a, b or both.

Comment: @alastairtree OK, but can you explain why declaring `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` as prerequisites of `default` is not solving your problem?

Comment: @alastairtree And also, do you know that make is able to run several jobs in parallel (see the `-j` option)? If it does, and you do not declare `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` as prerequisites of `default`, you will not even have the guarantee that just `make a` builds `a_prereq` before `default`. So, if this order is important and, for any reason, you don't want to declare `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` as prerequisites of `default`, consider using the `.NOTPARALLEL` pseudo-target.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I think that default suggestion is logically the same as the "make c" in the question, and yes I could add a target/tweak the default target but I want to know if it is possibl. I need to be able to run 3 types of build, a, b and a+b. assume i have 100s of developers who type "make a" or "make b" every day and I want to introduce a new combined flavour "a b" without breaking their musle memory. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an XY problem. What you apparently want (not 100% sure) is to force `default` to be built after `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` if and only if the `a` and `b` goals are passed on the command line. This is quite strange and not really what make is intended for but let's give it a try.

Forcing `default` to be built after `a_prereq` and `b_prereq`, even with parallel make, is straightforward: declare them as prerequisites of `default` (indeed, I do not know another way to do it):

```
default: a_prereq b_prereq
    @echo "made!"
```

Or, if you prefer to separate the declaration of prerequisites from that of the recipe:

```
default: a_prereq b_prereq

default:
    @echo "made!"
```

But as you want this only if the `a` and `b` goals are passed on the command line we need to detect this situation. Fortunately the `MAKECMDGOALS` GNU make variable lists the goals specified on the command line. So a bit of `filter` applied to it should make it.

We can set make variable `MATCH` to string `ab` if and only if the `a` and `b` goals are passed on the command line. And we can use make conditionals (`ifeq`) to declare `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` as prerequisites of `default` if and only if `$(MATCH)` equals `ab`. Just add the following 4 lines to your Makefile:

```
MATCH := $(filter a,$(MAKECMDGOALS))$(filter b,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
ifeq ($(MATCH),ab)
default: a_prereq b_prereq
endif
```

Note: if the real `default` recipe makes use of automatic variables that expand as prerequisites (`$<`, `$^`, ...) you will have to remember that their values are different for `make a` and for `make a b`...

Note: if targets `a` and `b` must be rebuild but are not passed as goals on the command line this will not work. For instance, if `a` and `b` are prerequisites of another, requested, goal. This is one of the main reasons why what you ask for looks so strange.

Note: if you also need to build `default` after `a_prereq` when running `make a` (same for `b`) an even simpler solution would be:

```
default: $(patsubst %,%_prereq,$(filter a b,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
```

This way, if you run `make a`, `a_prereq` is declared as prerequisite of `default`, if you run `make b`, `b_prereq` is declared as prerequisite of `default`, is you run `make a b` both `a_prereq` and `b_prereq` are declared as prerequisites of `default`, and if you run `make foo`, `default` has no prerequisites at all.

Comment: This is perfect - I did not know you could use functions in the target prerequisite  definition so that looks like a nice and tidy way to achieve what i want. Thanks!